# Issue with javascript in Chrome window created by extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that creates a new Chrome window and loads a URL in the newly created window.

This works as expected, but the URL that is being loaded in the new window is seeing errors that prevent the Javascript on the page from executing. The same URL works without any errors when loaded in a Chrome window created manually.

I have tried loading the URL in a regular Chrome window and in a Chrome window created programmatically by my Chrome extension. I have also removed ALL other functionality from the Chrome extension to verify that our Chrome extension does not have any other impact.

Here is how I'm creating the new window and loading the URL:

```
chrome.windows.create({
      url: 'https://...',
      type: 'normal',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: window.screen.width || 1000,
      height: window.screen.height || 600
    }, function(newWindow) {
```

The URL should load exactly the same whether manually by pasting the URL in a Chrome window created by going to File > New Window and those created programmatically via a Chrome extension.

What is the difference between the Chrome windows created by going to File > New Window and those created programmatically via a Chrome extension? What might cause the URL to load or execute Javascript differently in windows created by the Chrome extension?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. See if you can repro the bug in a much older portable Chrome and in Chrome Canary.

Comment: It may be possible that this has something to do with WebGL support. When I load up https://get.webgl.org/ in a regular Chrome window I get the spinning box indicating that WebGL is functioning as expected. However, when I load up the same page in a new window programmatically via the Chrome extension the spinning cube does not appear indicating that WebGL content is not rendering.

Comment: Still sounds like a bug in Chrome.